# Alternate Access mapping

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I have a issue today with regards to Alternate access mappings.

My Intranet has two Access mappings as follow:

```
Internal URL              Zone       Public URL for Zone
http://servername         Default    http://servername
http://my.intranet.com    Intranet   http://my.intranet.com
```

The Intranet zone above is a DNS friendly name which routes to the server.

Everything seems to be working fine except Sharepiont logs on a daily basis a lot of Warnings which looks like this:

Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://servername with the URL http://www.google.com

Note the www.google.com part is different every time.

Is this something to worry about? How do I get rid of it? I can't disable the internal mapping as I have a application which struggles with resolving DNS and needs to connect to the Internal serer name directly.

Comment: We are glad you like our design, but please keep comments like that on our [meta](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) site to keep questions as straight forward and readable as possiblel thanx :-)

Comment: We have the same thing on our production machine but it turns out that this is due to a monitoring tool that is accessing URL's on the site that do not exist.  So these URL's make it into the ULS log.

Comment: Are you by chance using Google Analytics on the environment?

Comment: @webdes03 Yes we are, but those URL's don't seem to be showing up in our logs.  What we get are IP addresses that are from a monitoring tool the hosting environment set up, then removed.  Although incompletely as I discovered.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like SharePoint is getting requests for other websites routed to its IIS server. Remember that an HTTP request has an IP and a host associated with it. The request has the server's IP so IIS dutifully processes it, but there's no host header mapped to the URL being sent, so SP just kinda stares at it and goes "HUH?!"

I may be WAY off the mark on this, but my gut reaction is that one or more of your machines has a proxy configured to point to that server. That would cause the affected client machines to try to use the SP server to relay traffic to Google, MSN, etc. through the SP server and result in the odd hostnames in the logs. This is just a guess, but it's the first thing that comes to mind to me.

Answer (score 0):

There may also be a rogue/infected machine on your network.  Your network team should be able to look at your IIS logs and tell you where those requests are originating and take the steps necessary to resolve it.  For the short term, however, you can go into IIS on your SharePoint farm and simply have it only listen on the host-headers you are aware of rather than all of port 80.

This is not an ideal solution but it will limit any inbound requests to your SharePoint environment to only those URLs you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have configured bindings for your web application in IIS? It must contain information about all addresses from Alternate Access mapping.